# Example of application / website that use DHE for key exchange?

Tags: encryption, tls, cryptography, linux

I want to verify whether wireshark can decrypt HTTPS traffic or not when DHE is used for key exchange. For the same reason, I want to access some application or website which uses DHE for key exchange. I am unable to find one.

**Are there any Linux-based applications or websites which use DHE for key exchange?**

Comment: Many systems support DHE, though as one answer says, usually they use ECDHE instead for performance reasons. But DHE is still _very_ common.

Comment: You can also use `openssl s_server` usually with `-www` or sometimes `-WWW` to run **your own** minimal server with extensive controls over the SSL/TLS/crypto options. On (all?) Unix you can even do this on the same system; on Windows wireshark (really winpcap) usually can't capture loopback traffic so you need to use two systems.

Comment: If a post answered your question, please mark it as accepted! :)

Answer (score 3):

There are many websites that support DHE. From the top 10 million Alexa results, a scan in 2014 showed that nearly 60% of websites supported DHE. From [a blog post](https://jve.linuxwall.info/blog/index.php?post/TLS_Survey), the numbers are given as:

```
Supported Handshakes      Count     Percent
-------------------------+---------+-------
DHE                       267507    59.2524
ECDHE                     97570     21.6116
```

Many of these are just the result of Apache providing its default 1024-bit DHE, but it still shows support. Finding a random website that supports TLS will still give you a good chance of getting one which supports DHE. Wikipedia [supports](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=wikipedia.org) DHE, for example.

You can test if a standard website supports DHE using the `openssl` command line utility:

```
openssl s_client -cipher DHE -connect example.com:443
```

A website that does not support the specified cipher will return a handshake error.

Answer (score 0):

Most websites only support ECDHE because EC is generally faster.  However, I did find a website that provides DHE: www.netaddress.com.

Comment: How did you find it uses ECDHE? I have tried using wireshark, however no info about cipher suit?

Comment: There are lots of programs available that will analyze SSL/TLS connections.  We use this at work https://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/ for testing products, however for public websites you can use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/.